# Given $p>1$, why is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{p}\frac{1}{(n+1)^{k}}< \frac{1}{n}$

Tags: inequality, summation, geometric-progressions

I tried to take to bound it by taking the limit of the geometric series but it didn't help. I also tried to write: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{p}\frac{1}{(n+1)^{k}}< \sum\limits_{k=1}^{p}\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{p}{n+1}$ which doesn't tell me anything I don't already know.

Thank you.

EDIT: I think I thought too fast, does this work?

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{p}\frac{1}{(n+1)^{k}}< \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(n+1)^{k}}-1=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n+1}}-1=\frac{n+1}{n}-1=\frac{1}{n}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that this is merely a geometric sum, so we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^pr^k=r\frac{1-r^p}{1-r}$$

Take $r=\frac1{n+1}$ and notice that $1-r^p<1$.  You should then get what you desire.